# Recursive Arch Linux Shell Script To Get Dependencies

Tags: bash, list, recursion, dependencies, archlinux

I wrote a shell script to print out to a file all of the dependencies from a specified package. Obviously it's not working (or else I wouldn't be here lol). I'm new to shell scriping / bash programming. I am running on Arch Linux and have searched the web to get me to where I'm at. But now I get a bunch of errors from a "empty string package name". It starts off good, then it's an endless loop of doom. My current code is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter a package: "
read p

echo "Searching through package...$p"

get_dependencies() {
    # Make sure we get the package too...
    pacman -Sp "$1" >> myPackages.list

    # Get dependency list from current package and output to tmp file
    pacman -Si "$1" | awk -F'[:<=>' '/^Depends/ {print $2}' | xargs -n1 | sort -u > depList.list

    # Read from that output file and store in array
    listArray=()
    while read -r input ; do
        listArray+=("$input")
    done < "depList.list"

    # Get the number of dependencies
    numList=${#listArray[@]}

    echo "$numList dependencies from $1"
    echo "Delving deeper.."

    # Loop through each depend and get all those dependencies
    for i in "${listArray[@]}" ; do
        get_dependencies "$i"
    done
}

# Get dependcies of package that user typed
get_dependencies "$p"

# Finished
echo "Done!"
```

Comment: i bet you're running into cyclical dependencies (a requires b requires c requires a).  bash doesn't give you a lot of options for data structures to store this info. you could write two files: seen and deps and use `comm -23 <(sort -u deps) <(sort -u seen) > deps.new` to make sure you only get deps for new packages

Answer (score 0):

To avoid cyclic dependencies, you can keep track of what packages you've visited and which you have yet to visit in seperate files. Comparing those files before descending into the dependencies will hopefully keep your script out of trouble.

```
deps() {
   pacman -Si "$1" |
   awk -F'[:<=>]' '/^Depends/ {print $2}' |
   xargs -n1 |
   sort -u |
   grep -v None
}

alldeps() {
   # needed files, potentially cached for later
   unseen_f=unseen.$1.txt
   seen_f=seen.$1.txt
   deps_f=deps.$1.txt
   # start of with the root packaage
   echo $1 > $unseen_f
   # while we still have unseen packages, find depends
   while [ $(sed /^$/d $unseen_f |wc -l ) -gt 0 ]; do
      # read in all unseen, and get their deps
      for d in $(cat $unseen_f); do
         echo $d >> $seen_f
         deps $d >> $deps_f
      done
      # those in deps but not in seen to go unseen
      # we'll finish when unseen is empty: nothing in deps we haven't seen
      comm -23 <(sort -u $deps_f) <(sort -u $seen_f) > $unseen_f
   done
   cat $seen_f
   #sort -u $seen_f $deps_f
   # rm $seen_f $deps_f $unseen_f
}
alldeps xterm
```